# How to display markdown body wit Netlify CMS and Gridsome

Tags: markdown, netlify-cms, gridsome

My .md content file created by Netlify CMS looks like this:

```html
title: How to make dough part 1
subtitle: Measuring and Mixing
featured_image: /uploads/dough.png
excerpt: >-
  We will be getting through a lot of dough for this event. We need each batch
  to be the same.

  Let's start with the ingredients
---
#### **You must follow this exactly so that we have a consistent batch on the day.** 

**1Kg of flour will make around 8 to 10 pizzas.**

* 1KG of 00 Flour (Doves Farm Pasta Flour, Shipton Mill 00 or Caputo 00)
* 650 grams of cold or tepid water
* 22g salt
* 7 Grams (1 Packet) of dried yeast

Mix in the salt then mix in the yeast

Pour in the water and mix it with a nice big spoon.

Leave to rest in the bowl for 15 mins.

Turn out onto a very lightly oiled surface (just a tiny bit of oil) and slightly oil your hands. Do not add any flour!

Knead vigorously for exactly 15 mins. Don't just pummel the dough really stretch it and tear it up.

After 15 mins, shape into a ball. The dough should now be lovely smooth and springy.

Cover the bowl with lightly oiled cling film and leave to rise at room temperature. It should double in size.

Knock out the air and put in in the fridge until tomorrow or in the freezer if making in advance.

Dough will keep for up to 72 hours in the fridge

Dough needs to come back to room temperature to make the pizza. 4 to 6 hours.
```

My cms config looks like this:

I don't know how to reference the 'body' part and display as html. Any pointers